# Can't extend php class

Tags: php, class, oop, configuration, extend

I'm trying to move a php/mysql web application to a new server. The application runs fine on multiple other servers, just not the one the client wants it on. Problem 1 is I can't get errors to display on screen or in an error log. (I've posted a separate question about this).  I'm hoping if I can get error to display I'll have more to go on, but what I know so far is it fails when trying to extend a module.  I stripped down the class to just this:

```
class Module_Organization extends LmsModule {
    function Module_Organization($module_name = '') {
        die('Made it into the function');
    }
}
```

Nothing happens.  But if I change it to:

```
class Module_Organization {
    function Module_Organization($module_name = '') {
        die('Made it into the function');
    }
}
```

then it does execute the die statement.  So it seems that the extend portion is tripping it up.  But I don't think it's the code because I know this exact code works fine on other 5 other servers.  So I'm wondering if there is any server configuration that could prevent php from extending a class.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is in `LmsModule`? Maybe, something "special" ? Or, maybe something, that current server does not comprehend ?

Answer (score 0):

I compared the php.ini file to a server where it is working to make them match and it is now working.  I'm not sure which changed fixed it though.  Thank you.